# "Couldn't do" or "could do" in idiomatic context (Christgau review)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, idioms, idiom-meaning

Below is a review by music critic Robert Christgau of a Flaming Lips album. I've pasted the entire review, but my focus is on the first two sentences. Primarily, is it idiomatic to use "couldn't" here? Because unless I'm wrong, isn't the point of what he's saying that you don't have to hate Sgt. Pepper to think it "could" do with a little ribbing, etc.?

> You don't have to hate Sgt. Pepper to think it **couldn't do** with a
>   little ribbing, travesty, desecration. In fact, you could love it as
>   much as I do and think that. As hilarious sobersides from multiple
>   generations charge indignantly that the Lips and their various beards
>   fail to "interpret" the songs, all three modes of deconstruction are
>   in play on this grand hoot of a fore-to-aft remake. Highlights for me
>   include a theme statement that gains meanings it never had from its
>   attendant distortions, a creaky "When I'm Sixty-Four," Miley Cyrus so
>   sweet on "Lucy in the Sky," and Julianna Barwick adding just what
>   "She's Leaving Home" cries out for--a female voice. Only "Fixing a
>   Hole" truly fizzles. As for "A Day in the Life," yeah--the original
>   rocks. A-

Answer (score 2):

"Could do with" is a [generally accepted idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/could+do+with), and "couldn't do with" can be an appropriately used form depending on the sentence. Take, for example, this rewording of the sentence in question:

> Even if you love Sgt. Pepper, nothing says it couldn't do with a little ribbing...

You are correct that the author has used the wrong form in the given context, and the idiom is thus logically conveying the opposite of the intended meaning. If this inverted usage of the original were to become popular enough or regionally significant, it could then be considered idiomatic in spite of its "wrongness" (as in the case of "[could care less](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/could+care+less)" or "[head over heels](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head+over+heels)"), but that does not appear to be the case with this idiom.

If you are acting in an editorial role, you would be justified in suggesting a change or altering the sentence.